# xml node converted to json gives an error

Tags: javascript, xml, json

I know there are many similar questions (spent 2-3 days searching for solution)
 but the majority of them referenced to libraries such as **xml2json** & **json2xml**
which is not what im looking for...

So here is the problem: I want to read from **XML** and save it to **JSON** object using pure **javascript**, not jQuery, not libraries, just pure javascript. Thank you for any help!

0) xml

```
<ipod>
    <playlist>
        <name>All</name>
        <contents>
            <song>
                <title>Miley_Cyrus_-_We_Can't_Stop</title>
            </song>
            <song>
                <title>Miley_Cyrus_-_Wrecking Ball</title>
            </song>
        </contents>
    </playlist>
</ipod>
```

1) javascript // with error

```
var fileData = 
{
    "title":"non"
};
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", '1.xml',false);
xmlhttp.send();
xml=xmlhttp.responseXML;

for (var index=0; index<2; index++)
{
  fileData.title[index]=xml.getElementsByTagName("title")[index].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  console.log(fileData.title[index]);
}
//output:
//n
//o
```

2) jQuery //without error

```
var fileData = 
{
    "title":"non"
};
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", '1.xml',false);
xmlhttp.send();
xml=xmlhttp.responseXML;

fileData.artist = $(xml).find('artist');
for (var index=0; index<3; index++)
{
  fileData.url[index]=fileData.url[index].textContent;
  console.log(fileData.title[index]);
}
//output:
//Miley_Cyrus_-_We_Can't_Stop
//Miley_Cyrus_-_Wrecking Ball
```

Comment: So... you want to parse XML... _without_ an XML parser?  You mean you want to roll your own XML parser by hand?  That is far too broad a scope for a question here - open up the libraries you reference and read _their_ code to figure out your own answer.

Comment: the xml file could not possibly result in the output from jquery -- there is no `artist` field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

İf you don't initialize your fileData.title to a string but initialize into an object this will work with your native version.
change

```
"title":"non" to "title":{}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse the xml, you can just use regular expressions:

```
var titles = xml.match(/<title>([^<]*)<\/title>/g).map(function(x) { return x.substring(7,x.length-8); })
```